# App Engine Deployment Failed: Process Handler Exception - Non Zero Exit [2]

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot Java 11 project on Google App Engine.

On running mvn appengine:deploy am getting the following error:-

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) argument --version/-v: Bad value [1.0]: May only contain lowercase letters, digits, and hyphens. Must begin and end with a letter or digit. Must not exceed 63 characters.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:deploy (default-cli) on project demo: App Engine application deployment failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.clo
udsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 2 -> [Help 1]
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
<!--        <java.version>1.8</java.version>-->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <appengine.maven.plugin>2.2.0</appengine.maven.plugin>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.3m</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<!--                <version>2.3.0</version>-->
                <version>${appengine.maven.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <deploy.projectId>[project-id]</deploy.projectId>
                    <deploy.version>1.0</deploy.version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have searched various places and found out [Version Error when building Web App](https://github.com/google/loaner/issues/15). But was not able to arrive at a solution. Do help me out if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/maven-reference#appenginedeploy) and according to my understanding this is related with `<deploy.version>1.0</deploy.version>`. This plugin configuration tag reefers to `version` parameter of the plugin.

Although it's not mentioned in the documentation, the error states quite clearly that dot "." is not valid character for the version value. Only hyphens are allowed.

The documentation say that if you do not specify this parameter it will be generated automatically, so maybe its enough to remove it.

I hope it will help!

UPDATE:

In this particular case removing the tag `<deploy.version>` was not successful. However it worked with value `1`. Thanks @AyushSurana for update!

Comment: Thank for the answer. 
When I removed it completely it gave me an error. But when I just removed the .0 and kept the version as 1. It worked. 
Could u edit your answer so that I can mark it as the correct one. 
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I think this might be due to other details of your solution. I have added this to the answer. Most important that you was able to solve it. Happy Coding!